# Python or PyPy for small group and large project?

Tags: python, django, couchdb, pylons, pypy

Early stage of planning a large project - difficult decision of choosing frameworks :)

In mind:

1. "select way - run fast".
    Select technologies with growth opportunity, prototype as fast as possible.
2. "look at horizon - build a ship".
    Understand the scope, invest in difficult decision but reach the goal.
3. "take the best - enjoy the ride".
    Bring the best team, do not let them fall aboard.

Choose from:

HTML 5, CSS 3 - PyPy 1.4/CPython 3 + Pylons/Tornado/Django - CouchDB/MongoDB/Riak + Erlang?

First step: 3-4 developers in team + 1 admins + 1 designer.

Designer - View + Service Developers - Admin - Balance + Structure Developers

Second step: 5-7 developers in team + 2-3 admins + 1-2 designer.

**Updated:** Python + Pyramid (Pylons) + Couchbase (CouchDB)

Comment: You probably mean "CPython or PyPy", no?  CPython is standard, C-language implementation of the Python language.

Answer (score 5):

Go with CPython. All known bindings to external libraries or whatever are supposed to work with CPython. I doubt that you will have success with PyPy here. Just from the prospective of risk management in large projects: stay mainstream.

Answer (score 5):

Python (assuming you mean the CPython implementation) and PyPy are not frameworks, but implementations of the Python language. Note that they *implement the same language*. I'd start with CPython because it's industrial-strength *today*, and the multitude of Python libraries, frameworks and extensions all target it.

PyPy looks promising, and it may become a serious contender for the most popular Python implementation some day. But that day is still far away, and if it does arrive it won't be without PyPy's ability to run CPython libraries without modifications, so I think you're safe for quite some time.

Comment: I'm talking about the whole structure of the application. If we choose one implementation we need to think about support the rest of the technologies.

Comment: @Quiz: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Can you clarify in an edit to the question? I'm not aware of any technologies currently supported by PyPy but not CPython

Answer (score 3):

> HTML 5, CSS 3 - PyPy 1.4/CPython 3 + Pylons/Tornado/Django - CouchDB/MongoDB/Riak + Erlang?

Simplify.

Python 2.7, Django 1.2, SQLite and MongoDB  get started building stuff right away.

Add later.  Upgrade to Python 3 later.

Comment: +1, but I'd go for developing on postgres instead of sqlite from day one

Comment: @stevejalim: My preference is to use MongoDB for almost everything except Django's sessions, which are sort of biased toward a relational database.  SQLite is handy for sessions.

Answer (score 0):

It's good prqctice to mix technologies in scope of a project. Depending on purpose for example erlang may be more suitable than python.